# How to name number property for JSONGenerator

Tags: apex, api, json, rest, paypal

In the [PayPal REST API](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/#creditcard-object), there is a **credit_card object** which has a property called `number`. Unfortunately, "number" is a [reserved keyword](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_reserved_words.htm) in Apex, which means that I can't simply name my property `number` in Apex.

The problem is, if I can't name my property `number` in Apex, is there another way I can use the `JSONGenerator` class in Salesforce to automatically produce the correct JSON payload, given a correctly constructed `CreditCard` object?

Below is the relevant `CreditCard` class definition that I cannot save.

```
public class CreditCard {

    public String number { get; set; }
    public Integer ccv2 { get; set }
    public String firstName { get; set; }
    public Integer expireMonth { get; set; }
    public Integer expireYear { get; set; }
    public String lastName { get; set; }
    public String type { get; set; }

    public CreditCard() {
        ...
    }
}
```

In trying to find a quick and dirty workaround, I tried naming the offending property `_number` and `number_`, both of which could not be saved.

Trying to save `_number` gave me:

> line 40:22 no viable alternative at character '_'

Trying to save `number_` gave me:

> Invalid identifier: number_

Is there some other way to name the property so that I can just run my object through JSONGenerator? Or is there another alternative for me to efficiently get the correct JSON representation of the **credit_card object** without having to manually piece together the JSON body?

Comment: Its simple change number to ccnumber which is unique property in your class and after generating json string replace ccnumber with number just like string.replace('ccnumber','number');

Comment: Yeah its a pity there isn't an annotation to control the JSON serialize/deserialze. Another work-around approach is to hold the values in a Map<String, Object> so that the key values can be any string and serialize the Map. (You can get fancy and add set/get properties that update/access that underlying Map too if you like.) This is assuming you want to use the convenient JSON.serialize/JSON.deserialize methods.